# How to pass cookie as header in angularjs to a remote application that uses drupal [403 Forbidden]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, cookies, drupal-7

Good day,  I am trying to make a $http get request to a remote application that uses drupal in agular.js. Everytime I make a get request i get a 403 response saying [annonymus user]. I am able to make a put request and get a response with a token, session_name, and session_id. My problem is **I am not sure how to pass the cookie as part of the request headers. ** **I tried passing cookies as the headers and I still get a 403 response.** Any advice will help. I even tried to use *$cookie.put('KEY,cookie)* to save the cookie but still I get the same response.

```
var headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Cookie':xxxxxx=tokexxxx};

$http.get(url,headers).success(function(data){
        // response of the results 
        console.log('this is the repsonse that come from the get request', response);
}).error(function(err){// 403 error});
```

My LogIn service looks like this

```
angular.module('app.services', []).service('LoginService', function($rootScope,$q,$http,$cookies) {

    // this is the function that is called when ther user logins 
       var service = {};
       // get cridentials of the user 
       service.LogIn = function(username,password,callback){
            var loginStatus = [];
            var BASEURL=  http://xxxxxx.com';
            var parameters ={username: username,password: password};
            var headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

            $http.post(BASEURL,parameters,headers).success(function (response) {
              //  cookie.put
              // console.log('response::', {sessionid,token,session,user_data}
             $cookies.put(response.session_name,response.token); //
              console.log(response.session_name,response.token);
              localStorage.setItem('sessid',response.sessid); // locastorage 
              localStorage.setItem('token',response.token);
              console.log(response);
               return callback(response); //call this  on the controller
            });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try instead of "cookie:" put "xsrfCookieName" and provide the cookie name.
it should use the token it has in it.

```
var headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','xsrfCookieName':'cookieName'};
```

hope it helps

Comment: isn't the cookieName supposed to be the value of Cookie ?

Comment: well, cookies are more like a dictionary.
key, value
when you do $cookies.put(name, value)
same way in the headers, when you provide the cookie name, it will put the cookie value.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed some clarification